# Change color of region ImageMagick

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, image-manipulation

I want to change color region below but it doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong?

Only with -negate it seems to do something but I want to change the region to color #64F733.

```
convert input.png -region '444x294+530+85' -negate out.png

convert input.png -region '444x294+530+85' -fill '#64F733' out.png
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to "-colorize" it after setting the "-fill" color.

```
convert input.png -region '444x294+530+85' -fill '#64F733' -colorize 100 out.png
```